# How can I pull the data out of a pickled GeoAxesSubplot for re-plotting in a new figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I would like to "download" (save in a `pickle` file) a basemap loaded in `cartopy`, so that I can re-plot on one of two axes in a `matplotlib` `figure` using a different script than the one I used to download the imagery. I need to do this so that I'm not querying Stamen everytime I need a baselayer.

How can I pull the data from `p` where `p==<cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxesSubplot object at 0x124210e10>`

**Script 1**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from cartopy.io.img_tiles import Stamen 

def main():
    tiler = Stamen('terrain-background')
    mercator = tiler.crs

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([15.85583, 18.47056, 5.80167, 6.56194], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.add_image(tiler, 6)
    ax.coastlines('10m')
    #plt.show()

    pickle.dump(ax, open('map.pkl', 'wb'))

main()
```

**Script 2**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

p=pickle.load(open('map.pkl', 'rb'))
#plt.show() #works; but I want to integrate as a 2nd axis in another figure, now its own figure 

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axes[1] = p
plt.show() #shows two axes; but axes[1] is not the map
```

Note: I tagged the `basemap` package since `cartopy` is replacing it at some point

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily swap one set of axes to another in an existing figure.

What you can try in your **Script 2** is this:

```py
p = pickle.load(open('map.pkl', 'rb'))

fig = plt.figure()
p.figure = fig
fig.axes.append(p)
fig.add_axes(p)
```

There might be issues with positioning the loaded axes, which you can adjust by saving the position of the original axes and then doing `p.set_position(saved_position)`.